# Get coordinates and city when moving marker draggable mapbox gl

Tags: vue.js, mapbox

I have a map in mapbox which has a draggable marker, when I move the marker I am getting its coordinates and I save them in a store, but I also want to get the location, be it the city and the street or something more specific, is there a way to get this data in mapboxgl?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing [reverse geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#reverse-geocoding), a service that the Mapbox Geocoding API provides.  You can feed the lng/lat coordinates you get after moving the marker into this API to get back location data for that position.